# PhoneGap build using 4.3.3 cordova-plugin-file instead of 6.0.2

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap, cordova-plugin-file

I need to have the cordova-plugin-media plugin installed but that has a dependency of the cordova-plugin-file plugin at version 6.0.2.

I have that version locally and can only see version 6.0.2 in my local files.

When I go to build the app using PhoneGap build, it fetches 4.3.3.

How do I force it to use 6.0.2?

I have tried removing the cordova-plugin-file plugin in CLI and then re-adding it to get the 6.0.2 version which works locally.

This is in my config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="~5.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~6.0.2" />
```

I also added this line (not sure this part is relevant):

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

Due to an error in the build log but I still get the same warning.

I'm using the latest PhoneGap version (and have tried 8.0.0):

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-9.0.0" />
```

What ever I try, it seems that PhoneGap build always fetches cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 instead of 6.0.2 as specified.

I have also tried removing the plugin files altogether to force a fresh get, but still it just grabs the old version.

I'm building it online if that info is needed.

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this was due to the order in which the plugins are listed in the config.xml

I moved the line:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~6.0.2" />
```

to the first plugin to be installed. This made PhoneGap build install it first.

I did get another issue with the cordova-plugin-media-capture plugin, but as I don't need that, I just commented the line out.